# Why does obj.getBounds().height give a larger height than obj.height?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, displayobject

I'm new to Flash and ActionScript, but managing quite nicely. One thing that is continuously getting in my way are the `width` and `height` properties of `DisplayObject(Container)`s. I'm finally starting to get my head around them and learned that the width and height of a `Sprite` are determined solely by their contents for example.

I do not understand the following though: I've got a `Sprite` that I add a bunch of `Button`s to. The buttons all have a `height` of 30 and an `y` of 0. As such, I'd expect the `height` of the containing `Sprite` to be 30. Surprisingly, the `height` is 100.

The Adobe documentation of the `height` property of a `DisplayObject` states:

> Indicates the height of the display object, in pixels. The height is calculated based on the **bounds** of the content of the display object.

Apparently, the 'bounds' of the object are important. So I went ahead and wrote this little test in the `Sprite` that contains the `Button`s:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; ++i)
{
    trace("Y: " + getChildAt(i).y + " H: " + getChildAt(i).height);
    trace("BOUNDS H: " + getChildAt(i).getBounds(this).height);
}
trace("SCALEY: " + scaleY + " TOTAL HEIGHT: " + height);
```

This code iterates through all the objects that are added to its display list and shows their `y`, `height` and `getBounds().height` values. Surprisingly, the output is:

```
Y: 0 H: 30
BOUNDS H: 100
... (5x) 
SCALEY: 1 TOTAL HEIGHT: 100
```

This shows that the bounds of the buttons are actually larger than their height (and the height that they appear to be, visually). I have no clue why this is the case however. So my questions are:

- Why are the bounds of my buttons
  larger than their height?
- How can I
  set the bounds of my buttons so that
  my `Sprite` isn't larger than I'd
  expect it to be based on the
  position and size of the objects it
  contains?

By the way, the buttons are created as follows:

```
var control:Button = new Button();
control.setSize(90, 30);
addChild(control);
```

Comment: i tried to reproduce this with simple movieclips but can't, so my guess is the Button class overrides the get property for 'height' and returns the 'visible height' but the bounds returns the height including the hidden objects (those with .visible = false)

Comment: Yeah, this is nonsense - the 'Button' class is screwing up somehow.

Answer (score 1):

From Adobe :

Returns a rectangle that defines the area of the display object relative to the coordinate system of the targetCoordinateSpace object. Consider the following code, which shows how the rectangle returned can vary depending on the targetCoordinateSpace parameter that you pass to the method:

```
 var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
 container.x = 100;
 container.y = 100;
 this.addChild(container);
 var contents:Shape = new Shape();
 contents.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,100);
 container.addChild(contents);
 trace(contents.getBounds(container));
  // (x=-100, y=-100, w=200, h=200)
 trace(contents.getBounds(this));
  // (x=0, y=0, w=200, h=200)
```

Note: Use the localToGlobal() and globalToLocal() methods to convert the display object's local coordinates to display coordinates, or display coordinates to local coordinates, respectively.

The getBounds() method is similar to the getRect() method; however, the Rectangle returned by the getBounds() method includes any strokes on shapes, whereas the Rectangle returned by the getRect() method does not. For an example, see the description of the getRect() method.

---

From what I understand getbounds of a button is set to 100 as a default. Try increasing the height beyond 100 & still getbounds will return 100. My guess is that is some sort of default value set for every control particularly.

Also if you wish to get the height why not instead of:

```
getChildAt(i).getBounds(this).height
```

Use :

```
getChildAt(i).height
```

Comment: The issue is that you probably have a textfield inside. Textfields have a height of 100 unless set manually. Silly adobe.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be tracing the scale for the container object, but you should be more interested in the getChildAt(i).**scaleY** property (i.e. the scaling of the Button), which is probably 30/100 (0.3).

If the Button itself is not scaled (which is unlikely), then it could be something going on with the Button class's overriding of the scale and height properties to return values different from what its parent class's implementation would return.